# Contour integration of $1/z$ around 1.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

What happens if we try to integrate a function like $\frac{1}{z}$ over the circle radius one centered at one, since the function is holomorphic in the interior, but at the point on the contour $z=0$, the function does not exist.

What about the general case of a function being holomorphic on a circular domain and we take the contour integral on the boundary. How do we do it?

Comment: Like any integral, you cannot integrate over a singularity, so instead make a tiny circular loop around the point.

Comment: Since there is a singularity on the contour, one would have to define the integral first.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123070/9464

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation